# is it possible to create file handle with COM object that could be used by other php functions?

Tags: php, windows, com

If I have for example a filename that php could not handle like unicode. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
$FS = new \COM('/*some com object*/');
$handle = $FS->getFileHandle("file name", "w");
fputs ($handle, $data);
```

So php won't even see what path it's writing into.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how PHP couldn't handle the Unicode? It's very likely that the root cause can be fixed. Either way, what you show above will definitely not work. The formats will be vastly different

Comment: @Pekka웃: http://www.spinics.net/lists/winphp/msg09876.html

Comment: Ah, ok, interesting. (And terrible.) I don't think you can work around this - the only thing that comes to mind is renaming the file using COM after you have written into it